# JOINS in sql scenario

Tags: sql, join

I am newbie to SQL Joins. 
I have two tables

**Version**

```
Vid, VName, IsActive
1    V1     1
2    V2     0
3    V3     1
```

**Sub-Version**

```
SVid,Vid,  VName
1     1     0.1
2     1     0.2
3     2     0.1
```

In above tables each **Version** has many **Sub-Version's** .

I need to fetch results from the above tables where the output should be like this.

```
Vid, VName, IsActive, SubVersionExists(Bit)
1    V1      1        1
2    V2      0        1
3    V3      1        0
```

in above result set the column name "**SubVersionExists**" represents if the version has SubVersion records in **Sub-Version** table.

Hope this explains the problem scenario well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a version without joins, but using `EXISTS (SELECT ... )` which returns a boolean value:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/712bd/9

```
SELECT
  Version.Vid, Version.VName, Version.IsActive,
  EXISTS (
    SELECT NULL FROM SubVersion WHERE SubVersion.Vid = Version.Vid
  ) AS SubVersionExists
FROM Version;
```

Or, if your sql engine doesn't convert booleans to 0/1, you can use `CASE`:

```
SELECT
  Version.Vid, Version.VName, Version.IsActive,
  CASE WHEN
    EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM SubVersion WHERE SubVersion.Vid = Version.Vid)
  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END   AS SubVersionExists
FROM Version
```

Another version with `LEFT JOIN` + `GROUP BY`, if you don't want to use `COUNT()`:

```
SELECT
  Version.Vid, Version.VName, Version.IsActive,
  CASE WHEN SubVersionVids.Vid IS NOT NULL
       THEN 1 ELSE 0 END   AS SubVersionExists
FROM      Version
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT   SubVersion.Vid
  FROM     SubVersion
  GROUP BY SubVersion.Vid
) AS SubVersionVids
  ON SubVersionVids.Vid = Version.Vid;
```

Or you can use `DISTINCT` instead of `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT
  Version.Vid, Version.VName, Version.IsActive,
  CASE WHEN SubVersionVids.Vid IS NOT NULL
       THEN 1 ELSE 0 END   AS SubVersionExists
FROM      Version
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT SubVersion.Vid
  FROM            SubVersion
) AS SubVersionVids
  ON SubVersionVids.Vid = Version.Vid;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select v.vid,v.vname,v.isactive,count(s.svid) as SubVersionExists from 
Version v left join Sub-Version s on v.vid=s.vid group by v.vid;
```

Here `SubVersionExists's` value will be greater than zero if sub version exists for respective version.

---

```
select v.vid,v.vname,v.isactive, case when count(s.svid) > 0 then 1 else 0 end 
as SubVersionExists from Version v left join Sub-Version s on v.vid=s.vid 
group by v.vid;
```

This query will give the desired result i.e. `SubVersionExists's` value will be 1 if sub version exists for respective version else zero.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT V.VID, V.NAME, V.ISACTIVE, 
CASE 
 WHEN COUNT(SV.SVID)=0 then '0'
 WHEN COUNT(SV.SVID)>0 then '1'
END 
VERSION V LEFT JOIN SUBVERSION SV ON V.VID=SV.VID
GROUP BY V.VID, V.NAME, V.ISACTIVE
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey I have also found a solution for this question with `CASE` and `IS NOT NULL` and `DISTICT` with a left outer join

Solution:

```
SELECT DISTINCT v.vid,v.vname,v.isactive,
    'SubVersionExists' = CASE WHEN vs.vid IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM VERSION v
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
subversion vs
ON v.vid = vs.vid
```